# Can a separate WordPress (same server) get posts from an existing one, but have different settings?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, testing, wordpress-theming

When developing WordPress themes for a site with a large amount of posts, how can I dynamically pull existing post data from the live version of the site onto my testing site? I already know about WordPress's export feature, but that's one-and-done, not dynamically queried.

1. **Plan A:**

   - *Proposed Solution:*

     - Create read-only user in live site's database
     - PRECAUTION: change test site's prefix from "wp_" to "test_"
   - *Problems:*

     - Settings (like current theme) on test site cannot be changed, thanks to read-only user
     - No posts found in "test_posts", even though I'd like it to search "wp_posts"

Is there an easier way or existing solution to avoid rewriting WordPress system files on the test site? I'd really rather not rewrite WordPress's database interface...

**Similar:** [Linking themes across WP installations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997007/can-two-different-wordpress-blogs-on-the-same-server-use-a-common-theme-folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just duplicate the DB, re-name and call DB in wp-config!